# Unable to get value of route parameter from $routeParams

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm working on an angularjs application that is having an "app.js" file. This file contains the following code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])

app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
       .when('/UserProfileInfo/:UserId', {
           templateUrl: 'Views/Users/UserProfileInfo.html',
           controller: 'UserProfileInfoController'
        })
        .otherwise({
           redirectTo: "/"
        });
  }]);
```

As you can see that above code is having a "UserProfileInfo" route that receives "UserId" route paramenter.

An html page is having a link tag referencing to the "UserProfileInfo" route and the code for this:

```
<a ng-href="#UserProfileInfo/{{item.UserId}}" ng-hide="hideViewUser" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="View"></a>
```

This link is referring to

```
www.somedomain.com/#/UserProfileInfo/131
```

The controller code for this UserProfileInfo view is below:

```
app.controller("UserProfileInfoController", ["$scope", "$location" "$routeParams", "$q", function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, $q) {
    $scope.userProfileId = $routeParams.UserId;
}]);
```

The problem occurrs at this line:

```
$scope.userProfileId = $routeParams.UserId;
```

The UserId from $routeParams is coming undefined.

I have used all the required scripts on Index.html page:

```
<script src="Content/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="Content/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
```

Kindly help me I'm missing anything.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried and seem like there is no problem with your code above, `$routeParams` get the correct value inside `controller`. Have you tried update `angular` and `angular-route` to the latest version ?

Comment: use this js file in your index.html https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route/blob/master/angular-route.js

Comment: Maybe a slash is missing after the hash: <a ng-href="#/UserProfileInfo/{{item.UserId}}">Go</a>

Comment: I have the exact same problem. When I log $routeParams to the console I see all the variables, but when I try to access them they return "undefined".
Have you been able to fix this?